# Problem while moving a group of game objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created via scripting lines of child rectangles with random widths. They are all named like Line0, rectangle0, rectangle1, line2, restangle0, etc. They all have box collider 2d attached, lines and rectangles.

Now I'm trying to move those lines, only on the x axis, with the following code. It's works sometimes, but sometimes only once per line, sometimes multiple times per line, some lines don't move, it quite random, and I cannot find why.

Lines have a script attached to manage the movements, already tried with localposition and same results:

```
public class line : MonoBehaviour
{

    float startPosX;
    float startPosY;

    bool isHeld = false;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isHeld == true)
        {    
            Vector3 mousePos;
            mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

            this.transform.position = new Vector3(mousePos.x - startPosX, this.transform.position.y, 0);    
        }
    }

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 mousePos;
            mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
            //Debug.Log(mousePos.ToString());

            startPosX = mousePos.x - this.transform.position.x;
            startPosY = mousePos.y - this.transform.position.y;
            isHeld = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        isHeld = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That could be your issue.  I don't believe each line should have its own script since you can't be sure of the execution order of the scripts.  You should have one script that references all lines and when needed, update all positions from that one script.

Comment: Note your use of `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` is redundant, as that's what `OnMouseDown` already ensures. Also note there's `OnMouseDrag` which can make redundant the use of an additional `isHeld`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Line : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 startPosition;
    Vector3 mouseStartPosition;

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        mouseStartPosition = MousePosition();
        startPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        float x = startPosition.x + MousePosition().x - mouseStartPosition.x;
        transform.position = new Vector3(x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }

    Vector3 MousePosition()
    {
        Vector3 position = Input.mousePosition;
        position.z = 10f;
        return Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problems with this code, Maybe Jiveturkey is right, maybe is not a good idea to have that code on all the spwaned lines.

Comment: Yeah this does not work with the scripts on the lines